# Удаление ненужных тегов из html документа

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Допустим я через file_get_contents получил в переменную страницу, и мне с ней надо производить кучу операций, но на странице кучи мусора.
А производить надо операции только с содержимым, которое содержится в определенных тегах.
Если быть точным, то штук 40 `<span></span>` , а остальной мусор мне не нужен.Можно ли как-то выпилить все с header и body, оставив в последнем только нужные мне теги  и ничего кроме них?
Span имеют вид, где ... это то, с чем я буду работать в дальнейшем(там еще внутри span'ы):

```
<span class="thumb" id="p1521665">...</span>
<span class="thumb" id="p1521667">...</span>
<span class="thumb" id="p1526321">...</span>
<span class="thumb" id="p1521612">...</span>
<span class="thumb" id="p1521905">...</span>
```

Можно ли их как-то выцепить?

Comment: Системы нет, каждый спан - это загруженный объект, которому присваивается айдишник на рандоме.

Comment: читаем про `strip_tags`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$str = '<span class="thumb" id="p1521665">...</span>
<span class="thumb" id="p1521667">...</span>
<span class="thumb" id="p1526321">...</span>
<span class="thumb" id="p1521612">...</span>
<span class="thumb" id="p1521905">...</span>';

$patt = '~<span.+id="\w+">(.+)</span>~';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Работает, но почему-то делает 2 прохода и выводит два одинаковых массива.

Comment: Саму страницу получаю через curl, если это важно.

Comment: Сейчас глянул и в выводе получается, что он загоняет в массив вообще все спаны, без разбора.А можно ли как-то ограничить его, чтобы загонялись спаны, которые только с атрибутом id?А то получается почти что весь html в перменной оказывается, а мне это не нужно.

Comment: через var_dump array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }  выдает

Comment: @Mastas может вы где-то допустили ошибку, т.к. код работает, посмотреть можно тут _(кликнуть по кнопке Execute Code)_ [Смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a27ee6bf2f254ab82836020757875471a4e6514)